# Integrating Echarts Transform with Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, echarts

I have a project where I am trying to use a simple transform with echarts and vue 3, but am not having luck getting the graph to render. The following example code is below:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-echarts-vue-3-ltlcyr?file=src/App.vue

TransformComponent is imported, but I'm not sure if there is anything else that needs to be imported or changed in addition to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also import the DatasetComponent in addition to the TransformComponent

```
import {
  DatasetComponent,
  TransformComponent
} from 'echarts/components';

echarts.use([
  DatasetComponent,
  TransformComponent
]);
```